# change css of next div having a class

Tags: jquery, css

Click on `title` should change css of next div having `target` class.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.target').css('background', 'gold');
});
```

```css
.title{cursor:pointer;}
.target{background:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<br>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<input type='text'>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<div class='subtitle'>sub</div>
<div class='target'>targ</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$(this).next().next('.target')`. Because

> - `$(this).next()` is the `<br>` tag
> - so `$(this).next().next('.target')` will give you the:
>    `<div class='target'>targ</div>`

Try the following code, it should work fine.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().next('.target').css('background', 'gold');
});
```

```css
.title{cursor:pointer;}
.target{background:lightgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<br>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<input type='text'>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title'>TITLE</div>
<div class='subtitle'>sub</div>
<div class='target'>targ</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector)

> **Get the immediately following sibling of each element** in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

So in your case the *immediately following sibling* is `<br>`, which doesn't have the class `.target`. Thus you are not seeing any effect of the click, as no **gold** background color is being applied. But you could write the code as:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".title", function(e) {
  $(e.target)
    .find("~ .target:first")
    .css("background", "gold");
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.target {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' data-id="1">TITLE</div>
<br>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title' data-id="122">TITLE</div>
<input type='text'>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title' data-id="11">TITLE</div>
<div class='subtitle'>sub</div>
<div class='target'>targ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `nextAll()` is smarter and less code.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.target').first().css('background', 'gold');
});
```

```css
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.target {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' data-id="1">TITLE</div>
<br>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title' data-id="122">TITLE</div>
<input type='text'>
<div class='target'>targ</div>

<div class='title' data-id="11">TITLE</div>
<div class='subtitle'>sub</div>
<div class='target'>targ</div>
```